# How can I retrieve other table's data as an object?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select
  e.*,
  c.*
from
  restaurants e
  inner join restaurants_social c on e.id = c.id
```

And this one returns the result like this

```
{
  id: 10,
  address: 'asjofosifje 23'
  instagram: 'sadf'
  .....
}
```

However, I want to have it like that. What should I change in order to make 'social_media' as an object?

```
{
  id: 10,
  address: 'asjofosifje 23'
  social_media: {
    instagram: 'sadf'
    ......
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not what SQL is for... if you want an object-store, go use MongoDB or Redis. SQL Server is not an object-store; it's a database of relations (tuples) that (tries to...) follow Codd's prophetic vision of normalized data banks.

Comment: ahhh, so I can't do that in postgres?

Comment: Well, you _can_ - but only by abusing Postgres' (and MSSQL's) `JSON` functions - but that's just _doing it wrong_ on so many levels. As an alternative, I'll say you need to learn about, understand and embrace _normalized relational tuples_ and you'll see why we don't return "objects" from databases.

Comment: ahhh i seeeee! THank you very muuuch!

Comment: [Now, come and join the enlightened!](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~zives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf)

Comment: Where and how do you use the query shown? Probably in some kind of programming language, like Python, Java, etc? All of these languages have libraries that map one-to-many relationships to a collection of objects.

Comment: This can easily be done in PostgreSQL using the JSON construction functions. But the question is unclear: what should the result be if the query returns several rows?

Comment: [{id: 10, address: 'asf', social_media: {...}}, {id: 10, address: 'asf', social_media: {...}},{id: 10, address: 'asf', social_media: {...}}] something like this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how these relate to each other. To get a `social_media` as opposed to *values of `social_media`*, just don't unpack it. Notice the missing `.*`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/aFQr0NW6)

```sql
select
  e.*,
  c
from
  restaurants e
  inner join restaurants_social c on e.id = c.id;
```

Chances are, your mapper will give you exactly what you showed. Problem is I'd expect each `restaurant` to have many `restaurants_social`, in which case you'll need to aggregate. For each restaurant `array_agg(c)` will get you an array of their `restaurants_social`, entirely mappable to array of the given entity.

The [`jsonb` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) give you full control over the JSON structure you retrieve but that's sort of duplicating what your ORM already does:

```sql
select
  to_jsonb(e) || jsonb_build_object('social_media',c)
from
  restaurants e
  inner join restaurants_social c on e.id = c.id;
```

| restaurant_with_social |
| --- |
| { "id": 1, "name": "restaurant1", "address": "180 Prince St, New York, NY 10012, United States", "social_media": { "x": "x.com/ristoranti1", "id": 1, "facebook": "fb.com/rest_1", "instagram": "instagram.com/rastaurant1" } } |

Comment: Does it cause a performance issue when it has a lot of tables? I was going to use the backend to retrieve the data and then send it to my frontend. But, if it is just the same doing it on SQL, I rather do it on SQL.

Comment: Encoding the structures as `json` is a pretty light operation on its own so I doubt it'll add much load to your db. Fetching the JSON will be "heavier" on the wire - it might transfer like a long text, whereas fetching those values the regular way sends all non-text in their proper numeric representations - as long as the client knows the protocol. It's best to always test how things will behave on your data, on your specific systems, but I'd say if you want that data as JSON, *some* part of your system has to handle it and the db is as good a place as any.